# What happened to the legal decisions of moshe rabenu?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, kabbalat-hatorah, halacha-lemoshe-misinai

Parshas Yisro, 2nd aliya (ch. 18 verse 13)

וַֽיְהִי֙ מִמָּ֣חֳרָ֔ת וַיֵּ֥שֶׁב משֶׁ֖ה לִשְׁפֹּ֣ט אֶת־הָעָ֑ם וַיַּֽעֲמֹ֤ד הָעָם֙ עַל־משֶׁ֔ה מִן־הַבֹּ֖קֶר עַד־הָעָֽרֶב

It came about on the next day that Moses sat down to judge the people, and the people stood before Moses from the morning until the evening.
(translation from chabad.org)

Where are these decisions referenced and if they aren't then why not?

Comment: Why should they be referenced anywhere?

Comment: Maybe modify the question "Where are these decisions referenced and if they aren't then _why does the Torah mention this incident_?"

Comment: As @robev mentions. Why would there be any need to record them. I believe these judgements were personal ones, how individual people needed to act according to Jewish Law. -  "They would come to him to ask what they were to do and he would instruct them, and so the judges. This would not be restricted to just ruling on cases, but any instance of doubt as to what G-d’s law required." https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/biblical-basis-rabbinic-authority